# Laravel / Twilio: Twilio\Exceptions\ConfigurationException Credentials are required to create a Client

Tags: laravel, twilio

So I am trying to use the SMS (text message) function in Laravel / Twilio - I have a local machine which I tested it on and the credentials and everything works fine- I use the same code on my remote machine (which worked fine yesterday) and today I am getting an error: "Error: Credentials are required to create a Client"

I have triple confirmed the credentials are correct, I have even hard coded them into the code , I have moved them from the env file to config file and still not working - I have retested my local machine and it works still - I have copied the code from local machine (working) to remote machine and still not working - the only difference between the two is I have changed the SMTP settings in the env file (even if I remove this , the problem still exists). I have cleared cache, restarted services.

my .env file

```
TWILIO_SID=xxxxxxxxxx
TWILIO_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TWILIO_FROM=+1xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

my Twiliocontroller:

```
 public function smsSend()
    {
        $receiverNumber = "+111111111";
        $message = "Sup Dude";

        try {

            $account_sid = getenv("TWILIO_SID");
            $auth_token = getenv("TWILIO_TOKEN");
            $twilio_number = getenv("TWILIO_FROM");

            $client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
            $client->messages->create($receiverNumber, [
                "from" => $twilio_number,
                "body" => $message,
                "statusCallback" => "https://webhook.site/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            ]);

            dd('SMS Sent Successfully.');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            dd("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

My web.php

```
 Route::get('/smssend', [TwilioController::class, 'smsSend'])->name('smsSend');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: May be try to clear the config cache. Try run `php artisan config:clear`. Or if you still want it tobe cached, to re-set the cache run `php artisan config:cache`.

Comment: that did it , thank you , wow - so simple. Many thanks and grey hairs

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it solved the problem :).

Comment: Add that as an answer @DharmaSaputra! It deserves all the up votes!